# Checking individual capture groups

Tags: java, regex, http

I have a single HTTP request that I have constructed an expression for. So far the expression works, and I could just split the request into an array of strings, but I would like to see if I could simplify it by matching individual capture groups instead.

So:

```
private void process(final String message) {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(GET|get){1}\\s(/.*)\\s(HTTP|http)(/1\\.0)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);    
}
```

And the request is something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Very simple. So, is there any way that I can go through each capture group to check if there is a match? Say the request had POST instead of GET, is it possible to check the first capture group and then return a 501 "not implemented" response?

My first solution was to simply split message by whitespace, and then check each individual array element. But that seems  a bit "bad".

**EDIT:**

Problem is, matches() matches the whole thing, and if one group fails, the whole expression then fails, which I don't want. It should be possible for any number of groups to fail/succeed, without throwing IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To still match even when certain groups don't they need to be optional.

Then use the `Matcher#find()` method as well as `Matcher#group(x)` to access the groups (starting at 1, since 0 is the entire match).

Example:

```
String msg = "GET HTTP 200 OK"; //resource and protocol version are left out by purpose

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(GET|get)?\\s(/[^\\s]*)?\\s(HTTP|http)?(/1\\.0)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( msg );

while ( matcher.find() )
{
  System.out.println(matcher.group( 1 ));  //prints GET
  System.out.println(matcher.group( 2 ));  //prints null since there's no resource
  System.out.println(matcher.group( 3 ));  //prints HTTP
  System.out.println(matcher.group( 4 ));  //prints null since there's no version string
}
```

As a side note, I needed to adjust your expression a little, since the second group `(/.*)` would greedily match anything after the first slash. It's still far from perfect, though.

A second approach might be to apply multiple expressions/patterns and apply them to the matcher one after another.

Example:

```
Pattern methodPattern = Pattern.compile("GET|get");
Matcher matcher = methodPattern.matcher( msg );

if ( matcher.find() )
{
  System.out.println("method: " + matcher.group());
}

if ( matcher.usePattern( Pattern.compile("\\s/([^\\s]*)") ).find() )
{
  System.out.println("resource: " + matcher.group(1));
}

if ( matcher.usePattern( Pattern.compile("HTTP|http") ).find() )
{
  System.out.println("protocol: " + matcher.group());
}

if ( matcher.usePattern( Pattern.compile("/(\\d\\.\\d)") ).find() )
{
  System.out.println("version: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

This uses the fact that the read position of the matcher is set to the position after a match and any subsequent calls to `find()` would start from there. If the pattern doesn't match, the position is kept unchanged.

Thus the patterns would have to be applied in order but are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You know that after doing the `matches()`, `Matcher` also allows you to extract the matched contents of a particular group with the `group()` method? You would however need to adjust your pattern to match both GET and POST (and whatever other method). Once you retrieve the relevant string like this, you can again match a(nother) pattern on it, or use it in one of various conditional constructs... (`switch` statements work on `String` too nowadays (Java 7).)

A different strategy is to match the delimiters, and allow *any* string as the HTTP method (even garbage). Then afterwards check the actual group value.

Still another strategy would be to have a separate pattern for each error condition that you want to handle separately, then see which pattern matches (if it matches, handle error appropriately). However, there are often conditions that one misses, so not all conceivable errors are handled. You really need to know what you are doing...

However, Java does provide a lot of networking library code so that you don't need to do this type of regexp checking. For instance, refer to `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getMethod()`...